# Reactive or non-reactive HTTP client should I choose to receive a big JSON in response?

Tags: json, rest, httpclient, spring-webflux, feign

I need to receive relatively large JSON (~300KB) as a response to a POST request.
In relation to that I have the following questions:
1) Which one to choose - reactive (for ex. WebFlux) or non-ractive (for ex. Feign) HTTP client to realize the best performance? (It's going to be up to ~20 requests/second)

2) Is my understanding right that we can send reactive style requests to any server? (or we should consider whether a server is able to work with reactive clients)

3) If I choose to use non-reactive client how would I handle a queue of requests? (it's obvious that it takes some time to receive a response with such a big JSON)

Thank you!

Comment: Keep it simple and go with the solution which is easier to implement for you. 20 requests per second is not something where reactive will provide you significant advantage.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, Martin!

Answer (score 0):

1. Regardless of the use case, reactive architecture always get equal or better performance metrics: I/O operation make threads to block in non-reactive programming, but in reactive programming those threads can be working in some other process (for instance, a new endpoint call) in the meantime. By the way, feign client has several reactive implementations.
2. HTTP Rest protocol is the same for reactive and non reactive applications. If your application is fully reactive and you need to do a call to a non-reactive application, the only thing to be take into account is that the 100% CPU usage is going to be achieve just in client side, not in server side.
3. Again, reactive or non-reactive do not have anything to do with request size. Probably you'll face issues having 20 request per second with 300KB of body size, but that would happen both in reactive or non reactive application.